# Installing QGIS LTR instead of latest version on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, linux

Due to major bugs on QGIS 3.18 I am forced to install the LTR version. But the official instructions here (https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) do only explain how to install the latest version.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

---

Update:
I followed the advice below and continued installation, now I got this:

`sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: python3-qgis (= 1:3.16.5+32focal) but 1:3.18.1+32focal is to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.16.5+32focal) but 1:3.18.1+32focal is to be installed
        Depends: qgis-common (= 1:3.16.5+32focal) but 1:3.18.1+32focal is to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-plugin-grass-common (= 1:3.16.5+32focal) but 1:3.18.1+32focal is to be installed
                     Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.16.5+32focal) but 1:3.18.1+32focal is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: That's not correct. The download page contains the LTR repository as well as the latest

Comment: Please review these threads: (1) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217727/broken-packages-and-unmet-dependency-installation-qgis-postgresql-and-postgis-u, (2) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350176/installing-latest-version-of-qgis-on-ubuntu-18-04, (3) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126673/installing-qgis-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 6):

QGIS 3.16 LTR will be installed when you change

`https://qgis.org/ubuntu`

into

`https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr`

in line

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu $(lsb_release -c -s) main"`

Comment: thank you for this. Applying that I get lots of these: **W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.list:4**

Comment: Google `Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: `$(lsb_release -c -s)` returns ubuntu release name which is `focal` for 20.04

Comment: yes, I considered that. I updated my question with new error above.

Answer (score 1):

You must write this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr $(lsb_release -c -s) main"
```